# saving svg: chrome default file name is not <title>

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I create SVG sketches with a canvas-type application which has a SAVE option.  I know writing files indiscriminately is a no-no, so the application's SAVE option opens the sketch in a new tab that can be saved with the browser's Save (Page) As menu item. The SVG code that is passed has a (title) element, which displays as the title in the tab for the window.  So far, so good.  In Safari and Firefox, Save (Page) As pops up a dialog with a default filename of (title).svg -- just what I want.  However, Chrome always comes up with the default of download.svg.  Is there a way to make Chrome use the (title) for the default filename in the dialog?

Comment: Does “opening in a new tab” mean via HTTP request …?

Comment: the new tab is opened in javascript with a window.open call

Comment: Yes, but how are you _loading_ the SVG image into that window? Is it an HTTP call to your server, that delivers the SVG data, or do you write it in there using JavaScript?

Comment: I write in the SVG converted to a string, using javascript.

Comment: I solved my problem-sort of.  I was using inherited code that has this behavior, I still don't know why. I rewrote my own version so it passes the SVG into some HTML and there is no problem with the title.